# Binding combobox to Integer array

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have created an integer array in XAML as follows:

```
 <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Int16}" x:Key="intervals">
        <sys:Int16>1</sys:Int16>
        <sys:Int16>2</sys:Int16>
        <sys:Int16>3</sys:Int16>
 </x:Array>
```

I have an integer property in ViewModel named Interval.
I am trying to bind this Interval property to the SelectedValue property of the ComboBox. However, the ComboBox does not show the selected value corresponding to the value of the Interval property. This is my ComboBox XAML code:

```
 <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Interval}" Height="25" ItemsSource="{StaticResource intervals}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="78,47,237,128" Name="comboBox1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="85" />
```

Comment: show us the Interval code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you should try SelectedItem  instead of SelectedValue because for SelectedVlue you also have to provide SelectedValuePath.

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public Int16 Interval { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = Interval;
    }
}

 <Window.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Int16}" x:Key="intervals">
        <sys:Int16>1</sys:Int16>
        <sys:Int16>2</sys:Int16>
        <sys:Int16>3</sys:Int16>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Interval}" Height="25" ItemsSource="{StaticResource intervals}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="78,47,237,128" Name="comboBox1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="85" />
        <Button Content="ok" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I got this working, but now i'm trying bind another combo with List<string> in a similar fashion - i have a string property in VM that i'm binding to the SelectedItem of the ComboBox. But here again the value is not reflected in the ComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

You created an array of [`short`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx) values. Your `Interval` property should then also be of type `short`.

```
public short Interval { get; set; }
```

If you intended to use `int` as item type, you would have to use `sys:Int32` as the array element type.

---

Also, you should bind the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property. Although it works in your case, `SelectedValue` is meant to work in conjunction with [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx).

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Interval}" ... />
```